# Possible to have code run just by importing class in Java?

Tags: java, output-buffering

Working on this one-class library where I need to disable buffering on stderr and stdout, if client imports that class, using something like

```java
// stderr
FileOutputStream fderr = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err);

// stdout
FileOutputStream fdout = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);

// stderr buffer of size 1
BufferedOutputStream errBuf = new BufferedOutputStream(fderr, 1);

// stdout buffer of size 1
BufferedOutputStream outBuf = new BufferedOutputStream(fdout, 1);

// add more features and functionality to stderr and stdout
PrintStream errStream = new PrintStream(errBuf);
PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(outBuf); 

// update stderr and stderr
System.setErr(errStream);
System.setOut(outStream);
```

Came across [static initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7), but unfortunately, they only run in particular [circumstances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1), none of which is of interest to me. Is there any way in Java to have the code above run only by importing the containing class (i.e., just the import statement; without invoking any methods, etc)?

Comment: Not by just importing I think, you would have to look into annotations, possibly write your own.

Comment: `import` statements have zero effect on the runtime, they only serve the compiler for name resolution. But even if it did work, it would be a _horrible_ idea because IDE's flag and automatically remove unused import statements.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking into the wrong place.

If you want that your application sends **all** stdout/stderr messages into a specifc stream; then you "simply" want to control that on the "JVM startup" level. In other words: you should look into means to manipulate the JVM as early as possible.

You don't want that redirection to be put in place when some of your classes gets "imported"; you want to have a robust way of directly telling the JVM on startup to do that.

But of course: the really **sane** way of doing such things is to use a **logging** framework which allows for much better control of what is going on. Logging to stdout/stderr isn't a good approach in the first place!

Edit: given the fact that this is about "training wheels" for students; then simply put a static setup method in some of your library classes (ideally taking to **strings** that denote file names where stdout/stderr should go to); and instruct your students to **call** that method as very first thing in their **main** methods.

Comment: This is actually pedagogically motivated whereby we provide this library as training wheels at the beginning. Not that we devalue learning about stream buffering, but rather we don't want students to experience/care about buffering, _especially at the beginning_, for simplicity. For the same reason, a logging framework is probably not an option for us either. But thanks for the input!

Comment: Sounds like there's no simpler way! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Imports are only used at compile time.

You say that static initializers are not of interest. However, static initializers run *when your class is loaded*. There is no way around it you cannot run code from your class without it being loaded, therefore I would say static initializers are exactly what you want.

The client can load a class without having to instantiate it, for example by using Class.forName

Example

```
public class Foo
{
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Class foo loaded");
    }
}

// different file...
public class Client
{
    static
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("Foo");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    // Nothing to do in this demo. The static intitizlier in
    // this class causes Foo to be loaded and thus invokes Foo's 
    // static initializer
   }
}
```